# Filter Flames are disabled in photoshop CC 2017

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, adobe-photoshop-elements

Just starting out with photoshop CC 2017 and I am trying to add flame in my image but `Filter<Render<Flame` this option is not active, after a lots of efforts and time I am not able to activate them and couldn't find what's the problem behind of it. Can anybody guide me how can I activate them?
[image]

Comment: What kind of layer do you have active?

Comment: At this time background layer is active but when I create new layer and active them then the result is same.

Comment: you also need to have a workpath selected.

Comment: Oh... I also select the workpath but the result is same.

Comment: Also you can not have the channels window activated on a channel

Comment: @joojaa my all window channels are active but these options are not turing on.

Comment: @Cai both these scenarios are different in that case Flame option is not available but in my case this option is disabled.

Comment: Start with new a clean RGB document using one for the facoiry templates. Anyway to debug this you need to describe what you DID do.

Comment: @joojaa in my all cases I am using RGB document and I also tried with new RGB document but I couldn't resolve it.

Comment: According to comments in the other question you don't have enough dedicated video memory, I assume that hasn't changed? You probably should have edited the original question rather than asking a new one

Comment: @Cai from the other question I just reinstall the newer version of photoshop CC i.e. photoshop CC 2017 and in this case I am facing this disabled problem and I have 1.5 GB vRAM in my pc. Photoshop is required 512 MB I think it is enough for it.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible this could be a bug in photoshop see: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1382327 otherwise it might just be that your device doesn't support OpenGL or could have 3D features disabled.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a path to use this feature. I found this helpful:

> You need to create your path first (using the pen tool or any of the
>   shape tools), then choose  Filter > Render > Flames. (Note: you need
>   to have a pixel layer targeted in the Layers panel as a landing place
>   for the flame to be created, not a Shape, Type, or Smart Object layer.
>   You can however convert type to paths or use the Type Mask tool to
>   render paths for letter forms).
>
> As you can see from the dialog below, there are a large number of
>   options that can be customized in a number of ways. The six different
>   Flame Types are:
>
> • One Flame Along Path: A single flame will be rendered on each path.
>
> • Multiple Flames Along Path: More than one flame will be rendered on
>   each path. The flames will follow the direction of the path.
>
> • Multiple Flames One Direction: Multiple Flames will be rendered on
>   each path. All of the flames will point in the same direction.
>
> • Multiple Flames Path Directed: Multiple Flames will be rendered on
>   each path. Each Flame will point according to the path angle.
>
> • Multiple Flames Various Angle: Multiple Flames will be rendered on a
>   path. Each Flame will point randomly. You can control the angle
>   variation by changing the “angle” parameter.
>
> • Candle Light: One candle light will be rendered on a path.
>
> **Source:** *[Flame Generation comes to Photoshop CC!](http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2014/10/flame-generation-comes-to-photoshop-cc.html)*